# Dynamically changing Label of UICollectionCell using a picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Basically I have a class setup with a UICollectionView and a UIPickerView.  As I have it now the picker pops up when a user clicks on a button within a cell.  What I am trying to do is have the text fields value change when the user selects something from the picker.  Here is how I have it setup but nothing is appearing when I change the value in the picker:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"cell";
    activityCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextView *nameLabel = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];


    nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",[arrayHour objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]], [arrayMinute objectAtIndex:[pickerView    selectedRowInComponent:1]]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you provided, you’re just setting the text once, not maintaining a live link to the text. You need to keep track of which cell the picker view is being presented from (for example, with an ivar), and in the delegate method `-[UIPickerViewDelegate pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:]`, set the text of the label again.